# Mips blank space on address

Tags: ascii, mips

So I have a string of chars. I need to check if a character is blank space " "/ ascii 32. How can I give an address ascii value of blank space so I can use it in if/else?

```
.data 
userInput: .space 40
.text
main:
li $v0, 8
la $a0, userInput
li $a1, 40
syscall

li $t1,0
    la $t0,userInput

loop:

li $a3, 32 #can i give this address 32 ascii value?
lb   $a0,0($t0)
beqz $a0,done
addi $t0,$t0,1 #going true the characters
bne  $t0, $a3, L1    # branch if ! ( char == ' ' ) 
addi $t1,$t1,1 #add blank space
L1: addi $t2,$t2,1 #add characters  
j     loop
done:

li   $v0,1
addi $t1, $t1, -1
add  $a0, $0,$t1
syscall

li $a0, 32
li $v0, 11  
syscall

li   $v0,1
addi $t2, $t2, -1
add  $a0, $0,$t2
syscall


li   $v0,10
syscall
```

Comment: Change your `bne` to use `$a0` instead of `$t0`

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks man it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.data   

         blankSpace: .ascii  " "

.text
 main:

         la $a3, blankspace
         lb $t3,0($a3)
```

Alternative you can directly load the ASCII value for `space` which is `0x20` in ASCII table.

```
 li $a3, 0x20
```

Comment: `li $t3,$a3` is invalid. In that sequence, you would want `lb $t3,0($a3)` to get the ascii space into `$t3`